# WebView Android увеличение масштаба Online карты

Tags: android, webview, openstreetmap

Имеется сайт онлайн карты http://www.openstreetmap.ru/ на котором у меня на firefox браузере работает так как мне надо, меняется масштаб самой карты двумя пальцами. Но на обычном браузере помимо увеличения самой карты увеличивается сама страница, именно так у меня получалось когда я вставил настройку mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
Как сделать что-бы увеличивалась исключительно сама карта а не страница?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю только писать свой WebClient для WebView и ловить нужный элемент с картой, обрабатывая нужным образом.

Comment: Это не хорошо, конечно. Я попробовал сделать увеличение путем нажатия на кнопки находящиеся на карте, у меня конечно получилось, но это выглядит как слайд шоу :( и как на зло подобных запросов нет.

Comment: в написании своего клиента для WebView ничего плохого нет. Там несколько обработчиков, да чуть больше контроля над страницей. Просто эта задача слабо связана с андроидом как таковым. Например, сайт должен по-хорошему быть адаптированным для мобильных ос, с четким отделением элементов тех, которые можно обработать, зуммировать и т.д. Попробуйте и напишите - это весьма полезно и интересно, если есть время конечно.